# Highlighting cells in excel based on another cell text that is derived from a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to highlight cells based on a set of values that is made from a formula. I have the data in the sheet from `A2:D10` (can be text, numbers, anything). I have compared this data with another sheet using formulas and have the text as `same` and `different` in cells `E2:H10`.

Now I need to highlight the data available in cells `A2:D10` based on the values in `E2:H10`. For example if the data in cell `G3` is `Different`, I want it to highlight the cell `C3` as 'red' and cell cell `E2` is `same`, I want it to highlight the cell `A2` as 'Green'.

I tried to accomplish this with conditional formatting, but it doesn't seem to work properly. Any ideas? Can we accomplish this with conditional formatting or with VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Antony](https://superuser.com/users/595474/antony-t)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1524502/911683) had the right idea, but misunderstood the question slightly. Here are the formulas modified for your use case.

In *Conditional Formatting*, you'll want to use the following:

**For Green/Same:** `=IF(LOWER(E2)="same",1,0)`
**For Red/Different:** `=IF(LOWER(E2)="different",1,0)`

[image]

Note that I added the function `LOWER` to these formulas. You may not need that, but I prefer to normalize input when I don't know where it's coming from. That way you can match `same`, `Same` and `SAME` equally.

Comment: Now it works, Good learning! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional formatting, you want the expression:

**[For Green/Same]**  `=IF(A2=E2,1,0)`

**[For Red/Different]**    `=IF(A2<>E2,1,0)`

Apply it to your range of data (drag and copy formatting)  and done!

[image: Test Data]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. My cell A2 and E2 does not have the same values. E2 have the cell display value of text 'Same' and A2 have some other texts. I have texts of 'Same' and 'different' in cells E2:H10(Actually cells in E2:H10 have the formula that displays the text 'Same' and 'Different'), but there are other texts available in cells A2:D10. I wanted to highlight the cells in A2:D10 based on the cell contents in E2:H10. Like if cell display text of E2 is 'Same' I wanted to highlight the cell A2 as Green &if E3 have text ' Different' I wanted to highlight cell A3 as Red and so on. Thanks